# Parsing strings with quote characters inside fields

Tags: perl, csv, tokenize

Suppose I want to parse the file

```
$ cat toParse.txt
1 2 3 4 5
1 "2 3" 4 5
1 2" 3 " 4 5
```

The first two lines are easy to parse:  `Text::CSV` can handle it.  For instance, I tried:

```
use strict; 
use Text::CSV; 
while() { 
    chomp $_; 
    my $csv = Text::CSV->new({ sep_char => ' ', quote_char => '"' , binary => 1});
    $csv->parse($_); 
    my @fields = $csv->fields(); 
    my $badArg = $csv->error_input(); 
    print "fields[1] = $fields[1]\n"; 
    print "Bad argument: $badArg\n\n"; 
}
```

However, CSV gets very confused if the quote character is contained *within* the tokenized field.

The above program prints out:

```
fields[1] = 2
Bad argument:

fields[1] = 2 3
Bad argument:

fields[1] =
Bad argument: 1 2" 3 " 4 5
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?  I'd like the final `fields[1]` to be populated with `2" 3 "` ... in other words, I want to split the line on any whitespace that is not contained in a quoted string.

Comment: I'd like to split each line on the space character `" "`, whenever the whitespace is not contained in a quoted string.

Comment: I think `allow_loose_quotes => 1` will do it.

Comment: `allow_loose_quotes => 1` definitely helps, but if there is a `sep_char` inside the loose quotes, the parser will still break.

Comment: The "I think" bit was because I didn't know what would happen in that circumstance. Ah well. As someone said, Text::CSV(_XS) is not the right tool anyway. And you have a very weird format on your hands.

Comment: yeah, I know its weird, but unfortunately I have to deal with stuff that looks like this all the time; data is not always smartly constructed :)

I always use regex to handle it, but I guess I was hoping for a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is not CSV, so you need to code your own parsing.

This should work for your particular case:

```
use strict;

while (<DATA>) { 
    chomp $_;
    my @fields = /([^\s"]+|(?:[^\s"]*"[^"]*"[^\s"]*)+)(?:\s|$)/g;
    print "$_\n" for @fields;
    print "\n";
}

__DATA__

1 2 3 4 5
1 "2 3" 4 5
1 2" 3 " 4 5 
1 2" 3 "4 5 
1 2" 3 "4" 5" 6
1 2" 3 "4"" 5"" 6
```

...and its output is:

```
1
2
3
4
5

1
"2 3"
4
5

1
2" 3 "
4
5

1
2" 3 "4
5

1
2" 3 "4" 5"
6

1
2" 3 "4""
5""
6
```

Click [here](http://ideone.com/LRV3p) to test it.

Comment: thanks.  I've been using reg-ex to parse (bad) data that looks like this, and I guess I was wondering if there is a cleaner way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Change quote_char to something other that " and the third line would be

```
1
2"
3
"
4
5
```

However the second line will now be

```
1 
"2
3"
4
5
```

So you would appear to have one line where " is the quote delimiter and one where it isn't.

So the file you are parsing is broke, and you are going to have to get clever.

Comment: I'd like to use a `"` quote delimiter for all three lines, which would make my desired output looking like : 

`fields[1] = 2`, `fields[1] = 2 3`, and `fields[1] = 2" 3 "` respectively

Comment: Eh 2" 3 " isn't happening imagine if the field delimiter was a comma

Comment: To illustrate the the difficulty you are causing the parser. With a quote delimiter of ' Then 1 '2 3' 4 and 1 '2" 3 "' 4 would work.